# Hadoop Mapreduce Job failes :java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop

I am trying to implement Hadoop Mapreduce streaming with python for simple word count example in this tutorial:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hadoop-streaming-using-python-word-count-problem/

my mapper.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

# Remove whitespace either side 
for line in sys.stdin:
    myline = line.strip() 
    
       # Break the line into words 
    words = myline.split() 
    
       # Iterate the words list
    for myword in words:
          # Write the results to standard output 
          print  (myword+'\t', 1)
```

and my reducer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from operator import itemgetter 
import sys 

current_word = ""
current_count = 0 
word = "" 

for line in sys.stdin:
   # Remove whitespace either side 
   myline = line.strip() 
   # Split the input we got from mapper.py word, 
   word,count = myline.split('\t', 1) 

   # Convert count variable to integer 
   try: 
      count = int(count) 

   except ValueError: 
       continue
   
   if current_word == word:
       current_count += count
       
   else :
       if(current_count>0):
           print(current_word, current_count)
       current_count = count
       current_word = word

if current_word == word:
        print (current_word,current_count)
```

my program is locally working when i use this code to run it

```
cat word.txt | python mapper.py | sort -k1,1 | python reducer.py
```

the output  shown in the pic :
[image]

but when i try to stream it with hadoop i get the follwing error  :

```
21/04/27 09:53:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1619506264660_0001_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:177)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:171)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:110)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.configure(PipeReducer.java:67)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/edureka/reducer.py": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 17 more
```

i think the error with the reducer because the mapper is 100% done as shown in the pic  but still not sure how to fix my problem :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the error is because i got wrong directory path for my  reducer